# How to get nested string from JsonElement?

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am getting `JSonElement` as Response from `retrofit` and I want to get only a string from it's object, so how can I achieve it ? I have browsed over too many sites but nothing found

```
 RestClient.get().getVoterSlip("Bearer " + Constants.ACCESS_TOKEN, new Callback<JsonElement>() {
         @Override
         public void success(JsonElement  jsonElement , Response  response) {

       // want to get a string here from jsonElement

         }

         @Override
         public void failure(RetrofitError error) {

         }
     });
```

I do not want to cast it with model class.

Comment: show your json response so we can help u better.

Comment: i have added code

Answer (score 0):

If you could share ur Json response, we could help you better. 
But first get the JsonObject and then get the string that you want.
for example,

> JSONObject jsonObj = array.getJSONObject(0); String theString =
>   jsonObj.getString("NeededString");

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html